# sed does not replace the string with special characters

Tags: sed

I've been trying to replace a certain configuration file that contains the following lines:

```
exports.config = {
  uncomment in case of directConnect = false 
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  //===run only one spec=== 
  specs: ['specs/login.js'],
...
```

And I want to replace the   **specs: ['specs/login.js'],** line with the   **specs: ['specs/register.js'],**

I've tried lots of different things but none of them actually affected the current line. It always stays the same. Here's couple of things I've tried.

```
sudo sed -i -e "s/specs: ['specs\/login.js']/specs: ['specs\/register.js']/g" conf.js
```

The line stayed the same.

```
line_old='specs: [\'specs\/login.js\']'
line_new='specs: [\'specs\/register.js\']'
sed -i -e "s%$line_old%$line_new%g" conf.js
```

But it still didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ sed -e "s/specs: \['specs\/login.js'\]/specs: ['specs\/register.js']/g" conf.js
exports.config = {
  uncomment in case of directConnect = false 
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  //===run only one spec=== 
  specs: ['specs/register.js'],
...
```

The problem is that `[` and `]` are regex-active characters.  `[` introduces a character class.  You want `[` as a literal character.  The way to get that is to escape the `[` with a backslash like `\[`.  Likewise for `]`.